# Apache tika: MSG remove extra line breaks in result string

Tags: apache, apache-tika

I have msg file with body text:

```
<html><head></head><body><div style="font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12.0px;">
<div>Test message.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>More content here...</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>Best regards,</div>
<div>Mr. Crowley</div></div></body></html>
```

I try to get content of the file above using Apache Tika...

```
final InputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.html");
final ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
final Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

final HtmlParser htmlParser = new HtmlParser();
htmlParser.parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
String plainText = handler.toString();
System.out.println(plainText);
```

...and all is fine except extra linebreaks:

```
Test message.



More content here...



Best regards,

Mr. Crowley
<and 3 empty lines here>
```

Is it possible to avoid this behavior? Is it possible to get more expected result?

Help me to fix this.